# Sum value of XML attributes using PowerShell 2.0

Tags: xml, powershell-2.0

I have a directory with XML files. I quickly want to go through them and sum upp the value stored in one attribute. I have figured out how to fidn the nodes I am interested in.

For example:

```
(Select-Xml -Path .\*.xml -XPath "//*[@Attribue = 'valueImlookingfor']").Count
```

This command gives me the count of elements in all of the XML files in the current directory which has the value "valueImlookingfor" in the "Attribue".

I want to sum up all the values of the "Attribute", not count them. What would be the best way to do this in PowerShell? I am new to PowerShell so this may be trivial but un-known to me...

All tips are much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$total = 0; select-xml -path .\*.xml -xpath "//*/@Attribute" | foreach { $total += [int] $_.node.value }; $total
```

Breakdown:

- `$total = 0` -- we're going to sum into this variable.
- `select-xml -path .\*.xml -xpath ...` -- return a collection of all the XML nodes matching the given XPath expression in any of the *.xml files in the current folder.
- `//*/@Attribute` -- return all the *attribute* nodes in any element, anywhere in the XML tree.
- `| foreach { ... }` -- pass ('pipe') the collection returned by `select-xml` to the `foreach` cmdlet.  `foreach` executes a given code segment on each element in the collection.  The collection element is accessed via `$_`.
- `$total += [int] $_.node.value` -- add to `$total` the value of the current attribute, converted from a string to an integer.
- `; $total` -- finally, return the value of `$total`.  As this isn't assigned anywhere, the value is written to the console.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not all familiar with PowerShell yet... much appreciated!